# How to detect Xcode version in a "select" with Bazel

Tags: bazel

Is there a way to use use the Xcode version value in a `select` or some equivalent dynamic mechanism?

The motivation for this is that we must support multiple revisions of Xcode in our pipeline and on our developer desktops. When supporting multiple Xcode revisions with the same build infrastructure it is desirable to programmatically modify the command line arguments used for the CFLAGS, such as specifying different optimization, debug, and warning flags. For example, we would like to specify certain flags only for Xcode 8.3 or higher.

I see there are configuration fragments for `xcode_toolchain` and `xcode_version`, but I don't believe I can select on those. We would prefer not to tell bazel which Xcode version it is using (for purposes of CFLAGS) either with command line config specification or by generating `BUILD` files dynamically if at all possible, especially since Bazel should already know which version it is using.

Is there a better recommended approach for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

> I see there are configuration fragments for `xcode_toolchain` and `xcode_version`, but I don't believe I can select on those.

What issues are you running into with the latter?

If you specify a config setting with xcode_version, for example:

```
config_setting(
  name = "xcode_7_1" + vers,
  values = {"xcode_version": "7.1"},
)
```

You should be able to select on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use repositories to do the local autodetection similar to how [bazel autodetects c++ toolchain](https://www.bazel.build/blog/2016/03/31/autoconfiguration.html). The resulting CROSSTOOL with be precisely baked for the current host, and no selects would be needed in BUILD files. If you need specific command-line flags to appear for a subset of rules, you can use 'features' for that. Features can be enabled/disabled on a per-rule basis:

```
cc_library(
  name = "foo",
  features = [ "foo_flags", "-bar_flags" ]
)
```

You might find [about the CROSSTOOL wiki page](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/About-the-CROSSTOOL) helpful. And to get more examples on how to write features and action_configs, take a look at [CppActionConfigs.java](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/94fbad5b230ae0c02a88100f1978d40d17d57b71/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CppActionConfigs.java)